# double click file sometimes does not open the file

Tags: windows, windows-10

I use Windows 10. And sometimes when I try to open Excel or MS Word file it does not open (although I have double click it). I have to double click again or again to open it.

What is the problem? Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Do you have Focus on the filename?  If not, it may be only seeing one click after achieving focus.

Comment: Control panel > mouse > check double-click speed setting.

Comment: Also check the mouse or keypad itself -- sometimes the switches wear out. As @Hannu suggests, check the double-click speed, which *also* would show if the switch is failing.

Comment: Open the Task Manager, make sure all Excel (or Word) instances are closed, then double click on that file and see if you can tell what is happening when you DON'T see the Word or Excel program start.